# Accessing DocuSign Sandbox on Mobile (Android)

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way of logging into the sandbox on mobile, specifically Android?  I.e. a sandbox-enabled apk that can be side-loaded, or some way to configure the main app to log into the sandbox environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, while on the prompt for your email address, if you tap the menu icon in the upper right you can select 'Choose Environment' and switch to Demo.

[image]